# create xml file from mysql data to slowly

Tags: php

I'd like to create a xml file from mysql data queries.

this part works well but it's very slowly around 15s to create a file with around 5000 lines.

On apache server, compression is activate.

See my code:

```
    $recordset = mysql_query($query, $link);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$rootNode= $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('DatabaseDB'));

while($row_recordset = mysql_fetch_row($recordset))

{

    $record = new DomElement("p", "");
    $rootNode->appendChild($record);

    $record->SetAttribute("id", utf8_encode($row_recordset[0]));
    $record->SetAttribute("np", utf8_encode($row_recordset[1]));
    $record->SetAttribute("pr", utf8_encode($row_recordset[8]));
    $record->SetAttribute("d1", utf8_encode($row_recordset[2])." / ".utf8_encode($row_recordset[3]));
    $record->SetAttribute("dn", (datefr($row_recordset[4])));
    $record->SetAttribute("tel", utf8_encode($row_recordset[5]));

    $record->SetAttribute("st", utf8_encode($row_recordset[6])." - ".(datefr($row_recordset[7])));


}
mysql_free_result($recordset);
mysql_close();

print $dom->saveXML();
```

If you have an idea to load more quickly, I'm very happy. 
Thanks

According answer, I try that:

```
    $writer = new XmlWriter();

$writer->setIndent(true);
$writer->openURI('php://output');
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$writer->startElement('DatabaseDB');
while($row_recordset = mysql_fetch_row($recordset))

{

    $writer->startElement('p');
    $writer->writeAttribute("id", utf8_encode($row_recordset[0]));
    $writer->writeAttribute("np", utf8_encode($row_recordset[1]));
    $writer->writeAttribute("pr", utf8_encode($row_recordset[8]));
    $writer->writeAttribute("d1", utf8_encode($row_recordset[2])." / ".utf8_encode($row_recordset[3]));
    $writer->writeAttribute("dn", (datefr($row_recordset[4])));
    $writer->writeAttribute("tel", utf8_encode($row_recordset[5]));
    $writer->writeAttribute("st", utf8_encode($row_recordset[6])." - ".(datefr($row_recordset[7])));

    $writer->endElement();
}
$writer->endElement();
$writer->flush();
```

But, with DomDocument, it's take about 9s to create file (5000 rows)  and with XmlWriter is arround 8s.

Do you have a new idea to optimize?
Thanks
So, the perform is not really better.

Comment: all looks good to me, what about query execution time? and what does datefr funtion do here ? use this [Determine execution time code](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2058/determine-execution-time-in-php/) to find out the actual time. start it from the new DOMDocument line.

Comment: For one, do you really require `utf8_encode`? What encodings are you dealing with?

Comment: Your issue almost certainly comes from the query, and you didn't attach it so it's hard to help you here :)

Comment: query work well and it's speedly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with DOM and the SimpleXML extensions is that they operate over big heaps of memory, then write to disk when you're done. Depending on the size of the query, you may be paging or spending too much time managing memory when you should just be streaming it out to a file.

Take a look at the XMLWriter() class. Set a file output and you'll be writing the XML directly to a file as you read in the rows. Will likely be a lot faster and much more efficient on large data sets. Make sure you use an output file and not the memory option though. Then when you're done, just readfile() the file you created to simulate your "print $dom->saveXML()".